# what has happend with my unity desktop

Tags: unity, compiz, nvidia-optimus

a couple of days ago I worked all day on my laptop at school, no problems.. then after arriving at home I powered up my laptop again and logged in. it loaded my desktop but unity was broken, I only saw my desktop wallpaper and my mouse. there was no top bar, side bar or hud, even the window decorations where gone.

I tried to fix this by doing a reset of compiz <`sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz`> and restart GUI <`sudo service lightdm restart`>.

I got my window decorations, sidebar and top bar back nut the top bar is not functional yet. the globalmenu is not working and I don't have a working system tray.

I'm stuck here for two days now and no one seems to be able to help me solve my problem, not google nor IRC have been successful.. I hope that anyone in here is able to help me fix unity?

my system: lenovo thinkpad w520 with optimus intel - nvidia (bumblebee installed with nvidia-319) 
my os: ubuntu 13.10
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried purging bumblebee to see if it makes a difference, most of my experience with this kind of problem is down to graphics. I have also heard of issues like this with cinnamon installed!

Answer (score 1):

Of course it was my own fault. In my Linux course at school I created a bin directory in my home folder. I created a SH script that printed `hello world`, and I called the script `ls`. When I rebooted Ubuntu automaticly added my home bin folder to `PATH`, and in the beginning of the `PATH` so my system looked there first and used that `ls` executable, this unity did not like very much. I removed the executable and worked perfectly again.